# How could transform list to Map<K,V> but not List<V>

Tags: java-8

Now I want to transform a list to a map, e.g.

```
    TaskStat t1 = new TaskStat("foo1", "bar1", 1);
    TaskStat t2 = new TaskStat("foo1", "bar2", 2);
    ArrayList<TaskStat> list = newArrayList(t1, t2);

    Map<String, List<TaskStat>> map = list.stream().collect(groupingBy(e -> e.getA() + "_" + e.getB()));

    assertEquals(1,map.get("foo1_bar1").get(0).getCount());
```

because the taskStat list comes from `group by` sql

```
select a, b , count(*) from t group by a,b
```

So every a + b has only one record.

How could transform list to `Map<String,TaskStat>` but not List?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Collectors.toMap` instead of `Collectors.groupingBy`

```
 Map<String, TaskStat> result = 
     list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(ts -> ts.getA() + "_" + ts.getB(), 
                                  Function.identity()));
```